# JavaScript: Why I can't see this property in my Object

Tags: javascript

```
var susan2 = new Object();
    susan2.name= "Susan Jordan";
    susan2.age= 24;
```

I can see the age property , but not the name. Some one help ?

exercise im doing right now :http://www.codecademy.com/courses/spencer-sandbox/1/5?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#

Comment: Please provide more details about `I can see the age property , but not the name`. Your code is totally standard so the problem is some place else.

Comment: What does it mean ? You have correct code. What is wrong ? If you are about output - there are only last message at right box ( change properties order and you'll see. Better to use normal debugger =) )

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KBpQS/.   So, there must be something else causing you a problem in your code.

Comment: as a result I see : "24" , which is age vlue . I don't see the name

Comment: What do you mean "as a result I see"?  What code are you using to examine the two properties?  Did you look at my [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KBpQS/)?

Comment: Yes I saw that demo. However in codecademy when I submit the code it gives me "24" as a result. Here is full code from the exercise :
// Our bob object again, but made using a constructor this time 
var bob = new Object();
bob.name = "Bob Smith";
bob.age = 30;
// Here is susan1, in literal notation
var susan1 = {
  name: "Susan Jordan",
  age: 24
};
// Make a new susan2 object, using a constructor instead
var susan2 = new Object();
    susan2.name= "Susan Jordan";
    susan2.age= 24;

Comment: @user3416944 I have used your own code here http://jsfiddle.net/KBpQS/3/

Comment: @user3416944 So do not worry your concepts are not going wrong anywhere!!

Answer (score 1):

When a bunch of code is pasted into the console it implicitly returns the last value and that's what gets displayed. Your last line is `susan2.age=24` which returns `24` so `24` gets printed to the console. You can add the desired output as the last line or call `console.log(susan2.name);` from anywhere to log the output

```
var susan2 = new Object();
susan2.name= "Susan Jordan";
console.log(susan2.name);
susan2.age= 24;
"name:"+ susan2.name + " age:"+ susan2.age;
```

produces:

```
Susan Jordan
"name:Susan Jordan age:24"
```